# VBA macro to create a chart works on one excel spreadsheet but not another

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am having an issue with my code. For some reason it works fine on one document, but on the other document it doesn't work. Below is my code:

```
Sub Graph2()

'   Graphs for monitoring

    Dim my_range As Range, t, co As Shape '<edit

    t = Selection.Cells(1, 1).Value & " - " & ActiveSheet.Name

    Dim OldSheet As Worksheet
    Set OldSheet = ActiveSheet

    Set my_range = Union(Selection, ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"))

    Set co = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlLine) 'add a ChartObject

    With co.Chart
        .FullSeriesCollection(1).ChartType = xlXYScatter
        .FullSeriesCollection(1).AxisGroup = 1
        .FullSeriesCollection(2).ChartType = xlLine
        .FullSeriesCollection(2).AxisGroup = 1
        .SetSourceData Source:=my_range
        'highlight final dot of data
        .FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points.Count - 1).ApplyDataLabels Type:=xlShowValue
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = t
        'ResolveSeriesnames co.Chart
        .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Graphs"

    End With

    OldSheet.Activate
End Sub
```

On the working document the graphs come out like:

[image]

On the non-working document the graphs come out like:

[image]

Any idea why this is the case?
The macro is located on a completely separate file to both these documents

Comment: What is different about those two sheets?  When you add a chart to a sheet it often picks up data from the selected cells - might be worth checking what's selected when the charts are added.

Comment: I suggest you sort your declarations of worksheets. It's safe to say that *every* use of `ActiveSheet` is a risk factor, and 99% of all `Select` or `Activate` don't serve a legitimate purpose. In your code the don't. `Union(Selection, ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"))` is asking for trouble big-time. I guess if you sort these problems of syntax and logic, very likely your code might work as you expect.

Comment: any pointers you can give me to send me in the right direction? @Variatus

Comment: @TimWilliams when I manually select the columns I want to be graphed, for some reason on the non-working document it deselects the first column I've selected - hence why I'm missing a series of data

Comment: If you step though the code with F8, at what point does the selection change?

Comment: Why the X-axis values on the non-working one all out of place?

Comment: Look at `Union(Selection, ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"))`. What are you supposed to select? One cell to indicate a column? 5 columns and then add column A? Say, you select any number of cells in any number of columns and then you want all the data in the partially selected columns included?? Say, column A might be included or not. If it's not you want the program to include it? Tell us. How can we guess? Look at ` t = Selection.Cells(1, 1).Value & " - " & ActiveSheet.Name` *Selection.Cells(1, 1)* is the first cell of whatever you have selected. There must be an exact rule for this. What is it?

Comment: It looks like some of the cells (the ones with data omitted) in the document aren't recognised as numbers. looking at a good way to convert all cells to numbers now

Comment: Don't forget to Dim t As String.

Comment: When you add a chart, it uses the range defined by the selected range, or the range that contains the active cell. I suspect the sheet that the code "works" on has a reasonable range containing the active cell, but the sheet that the code "doesn't work" on has a goofy range. Note: "the code works" is a funny phrase with ess details than you think. You have to describe in more detail what is the successful condition, and what is the failure.

Comment: I would examine the data in the two workbooks.